# How to resolve sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using Python Sqlalchemy for MYSQL db. I wrote the following script to create the class object and then add a row in the table.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.base import VARCHAR, LONGTEXT, INTEGER
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://root:@localhost/mydb")
connection = engine.connect()

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
Base = declarative_base()
metadata = MetaData()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'User'
    __abstract__ = True
    id = Column('id', INTEGER(display_width=11), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    email = Column('email', VARCHAR(charset='utf8mb4', collation='utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci', length=100), unique=True)
    password = Column('password', VARCHAR(charset='utf8mb4', collation='utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci', length=45))
    name = Column('name', VARCHAR(charset='utf8mb4', collation='utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci', length=100))

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

add_user = User(email = "testing@testing.com",
            password = 'testing',
            name = 'testing')
session.add(add_user)
session.commit()
```

When I try to add to session, it throws the following errors:

```
 AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 raise exc.UnmappedInstanceError(instance)
 sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class '__main__.User' is not mapped
```

I'm new to SQLalchemy as well as OOP so can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem stems from defining `__abstract__ == True` on `User`.

From the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#abstract):

> `__abstract__` causes declarative to skip the production of a table or mapper for the class entirely. A class can be added within a hierarchy
>   in the same way as mixin (see Mixin and Custom Base Classes), allowing
>   subclasses to extend just from the special class

If you make `User` abstract, to get mapped, it needs to be subclassed by another model, e.g. this works:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'User'
    __abstract__ = True
    id = Column('id', INTEGER(display_width=11), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    email = Column('email', VARCHAR(charset='utf8mb4', collation='utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci', length=100), unique=True)
    password = Column('password', VARCHAR(charset='utf8mb4', collation='utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci', length=45))
    name = Column('name', VARCHAR(charset='utf8mb4', collation='utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci', length=100))

class AUser(User):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

    add_user = AUser(email = "testing@testing.com",
                password = 'testing',
                name = 'testing')
    session.add(add_user)
    session.commit()
```

Comment: How would I map this if I have an existing table 'User' in my db and I don't want to lose the data that I already have. Because Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine) would delete the existing data that I have in 'User' table

Comment: I just include that line so that when testing the code it starts fresh every time. I'll remove it from the example.

Comment: Do you need to have `__abstract__ == True` defined on your class? If you remove that, your example above works.

Comment: I already have an existing database(which I created using MySQL Workbench) and the tables already exist. I'm creating table objects using SQLalchemy for the existing db. So, if I don't define  __abstract__ == True it throws an error that 'User' table is already defined for this MetaData instance. Is there an alternative to this? because I can't seem to add data to the table until I drop it first which means I would lose all the existing data

Comment: One way or another, the table is being mapped twice, or you have more than one model with the same table name in your app. Are you calling `Metadata.reflect()` anywhere?